# Find $\sup_{n}\frac{n}{\log n} \mathbb{1}_{(0,1/n)}$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, measure-theory, logarithms

For some sequence, $x_{n}=\frac{n}{\log n} \mathbb{1}_{(0,1/n)}$ (where $n= 2, 3, \dots$), find  $\sup_{n}x_{n}$. In this case, we are talking about a sequence of random variables over measure space $((0,1),\mathcal{B}((0,1)),\lambda)$, where $\lambda$ is the lebesgue measure, though this part is rather unimportant.

One can show that $A=\sum_{2}^{\infty} \frac{n}{log n} \mathbb{1}_{[\frac{1}{n+1},1/n)}$ will be this supremum by showing that it satisfies $A\geq x_{n}$ and $\forall \epsilon >0, \exists n^{*}: x_{n^{*}}+\epsilon>A$. However, it is claimed that one can actually derive this form of the supremum constructively (that is, there is a way to find this supremum without necessarily testing different values for it). Is this true? If so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- On the interval $[\tfrac13,\tfrac12)$, we have that $x_3=x_4=\cdots=0$. So on the interval the supremum agrees with $x_2$.
- On $[\tfrac14,\tfrac13)$, we have $x_4=x_5=\cdots=0$, and $x_3<x_2$ (since $\tfrac3{\log 3}<\tfrac2{\log 2}$)
- On $[\tfrac15,\tfrac14)$, we have $x_5=x_6=\cdots=0$, and $x_4=x_2>x_3$

Now the pattern repeats:

- On $[\tfrac1{n+1},\tfrac1n)$, we have $x_{n+1}=x_{n+2}=\cdots=0$, and $x_n\>\max\{x_2,\ldots,x_{n-1}\}$

So the supremum is 
$$
\frac2{\log 2}\,1_{[\tfrac15,\tfrac12)}+\sum_{n=5}^\infty\,\frac{n}{\log n}\,1_{[\tfrac1{n+1},\tfrac1n)}
$$

Comment: I'm rather confused - why is $x_{3}=x_{4}=\dots=0$? We have $x_{3} :((0,1),\mathcal{B}(0,1)) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{+} \not = 0 $ a.e. on $[1/3,1/2)$. Indeed, $x_{3}(1/3)=\frac{3}{\log 3}$ and $1/3 \in \mathcal{B}(0,1)$

Comment: Ah wait, $x_{3}$ is not defined there, I see what you mean now

Comment: The intervals where the $x_n$ are nonzero get smaller as $n$ increases. The anomaly at the beginning is due to the fact that $\tfrac2{\log 2}>\tfrac3{\log 3}$.